# Not able to Display images in apache

Tags: apache, xampp

I am running xampp on Windows XP. I can view the images in the localhost.
But others in my network are not able to see. The link for the image is broken.
Is there any setting that need to be changed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are the links to the image to the localhost or are they to your local drive (ie: C:\some\dir\image.jpg)?

Comment: Source code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are probably linking your images with an absolute path to `http://localhost/`. try using either relative paths, or remove the host from the path and point directly to the root like `/images/foobar.jpg`, that way the browser can construct the appropriate URL for your resources.